# Why Regular expression matches one character less at the end?

Tags: java, regex

Problem is last one character never gets matched.
When I tried displaying using group ,it shows all match except last character.
Its same in all cases.
Below is the code and its o/p.

```
package mon;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

class HackerRank {

static void Pattern(String text) {
    String p="\\d{1,2}|(0|1)\\d{2}|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5]";
    String pattern="(("+p+")\\.){3}"+p;

    Pattern pi=Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m=pi.matcher(text);
//  System.out.println(m.group());
    if(m.find() && m.group().equals(text))
        System.out.println(m.group()+"true");
    else
        System.out.println(m.group()+" false");
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    while(sc.hasNext()) {
        Pattern(sc.next());
    }
   sc.close();


   }

}
```

I/P:000.12.12.034;
O/P:000.12.12.03 false

Comment: Your regex seems way to complicated. What are you trying to achieve here? What is your expected input and output. Maybe we can simplify the regex. I've tried using an [online regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/ybOAXd/1) and it seems to be working fine. The answer that we're getting in your program is exactly how it's supposed to look like.

Comment: I am trying to validate IP address.At the end it should match all the 3 digits but it matches only two..thats why it gives output as false.

Comment: why does m.group() prints one character less?

Comment: Because it's designed like that in `\\d{1,2}`. I'm not sure what's your requirement but if you use `\\d{1,3}` then it will match 3 characters in the end.

Comment: Use `String p="(?:\\d{1,2}|[01]\\d{2}|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])";` and then use `.matches()` rather than `find` and you may omit `&& m.group().equals(text)` check.

Comment: Thanx , its working. I would be glad if you could tell me what was the problem with previous regular expression

Answer (score 0):

You should properly group the alternatives inside the octet pattern:

```
String p="(?:\\d{1,2}|[01]\\d{2}|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])";
//        ^^^                                     ^
```

Then build the patter like

```
String pattern = p + "(?:\\." + p + "){3}";
```

It will become a bit more efficient. Then, use `matches` to require a full string match:

```
if(m.matches()) {...
```

See a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/Do8D8f):

```
String p="(?:\\d{1,2}|[01]\\d{2}|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])";
String pattern = p + "(?:\\." + p + "){3}";
String text = "192.156.34.56";
// System.out.println(pattern); => (?:\d{1,2}|[01]\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:\d{1,2}|[01]\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){3}
Pattern pi=Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m=pi.matcher(text);
if(m.matches())
    System.out.println(m.group()+" => true");
else
    System.out.println("False"); => 192.156.34.56 => true
```

And [here is the resulting regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uyQQ4H/1).